# Zoom limit in Trackball controls

Tags: three.js

Do trackball controls limits zooming in and out?

As I zoom in and out of the object,object breaks at some point.

I want to limit zooming in and out parameters as in orbit controls.

I dont want to use orbit controls in my case.

Thanks a bundle.

Comment: Yes. `controls.minDistance`. `controls.maxDistance`. You can answer this question yourself by looking at the `TrackballControls` source code. three.js r.83

Comment: Thats my problem.I want to know whether it will support in three.js r.70.I tried in that but when model loads itself it happens and working like near far value,not limiting zoom.

Comment: (1) .r70 is two years old. It is wise to use the current version. (2) Look a the source code and you can answer your question. (3) Are you using a perspective camera?

Comment: I am using both perspective camera and orthographic camera. Will change camera type on button click.I am using trackball controls when using perspective camera and orthographic trackball controls when using orthographic camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was working with THREE.js version70 which doesn't support to limit zooming.
In current THREE.js version of Trackball controls we could limit the zooming in and out using the following code,

```
controls.minDistance = 10;
controls.maxDistance = 20;
```